# Can Firestore store data in IndexedDB by default for offline (and unauthenticated) users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, indexeddb

I have an offline first app and I am storing data in IndexedDB using Dexie.js. Is it possible to use Firebase to do the same thing ? In short, when a (unauthenticated) user goes to my site and enters some data into a form, I want *that* data to be stored in IndexedDB.

If the unauthenticated user decides to sign in (or create an account) and submits data ( to firebase servers) I want the local IndexedDB data and data on firebase servers to resolve and get stored at firebase servers.

From what I read this user scenario seems possible, but I am not completely sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore's offline storage mechanism is undocumented. Although I think it currently uses IndexedDB, there is nothing you can do with that knowledge.

That said: if your question is whether Firestore can continue to function locally while the user is not connected to the internet, that is indeed possible by enabling its offline persistence. This keeps recently read data in a local cache, and keeps a queue of pending writes while the device is offline, which it then synchronizes with the server once it reconnects.

I recommend reading the Firestore documentation on [enabling offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).